# Trailing white spaces only for javascript files in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In my user preferences in Sublime Text 3, I can set user preferences for trailing white spaces:

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

This is great for javascript files, but not for Jade (or other templating engines) where I need trailing spaces in my view.

Can I customize this option so certain files types (Jade) can opt-out (or opt-in)?

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html & http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization/settings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define file type-specific ("syntax specific") preferences in Sublime that override your user settings.

These preferences are set in the same manner as user settings, except that they use a different `.sublime-settings` file.

To edit syntax-specific preferences for a given file type, open a file of that type in the editor and then select **Preferences | Settings - More | Syntax Specific - User** from the main menu. (This simply opens the appropriate settings file, e.g. `.../Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Jade.sublime-settings` would be opened if you were editing a .jade file).

In your case, I would suggest leaving

```
"trim_tailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

in your user preferences, but then set it to `false` specifically for Jade files by editing `.../Jade.sublime-settings`, e.g.:

```
{
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false
}
```

Note: the above assumes that the `Jade` syntax has been defined in your copy of Sublime. While not present in the default installation, it will be created if you install a plugin made for working with Jade.